# Access violation reading location at cpp QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have problem with next constructor of QPixmap:

```
QPixmap* map = new QPixmap(100, 100);
```

There`s [exception thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLUuG.png), shown by visual studio.
Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000

I want to get empty field for drawing with current width and height, what should I do?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Include code and error messages as text in the question itself instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More specifically, you are trying to use QPixmap in a non-gui application.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64125

> QPixmap is connected to the underlying GUI platform, and hence
> requires QGuiApplication/QApplication to be initialized.
>
> QImage can be used instead here.